# Raising merge request for non-existent branch in parent repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, gitlab

We are using Gitlab for code management. Lets say there is a project ABC. Call is Parent/ABC.
Developers can't push to project Parent/ABC hence all the developers fork the ABC project. Create Branch. Make Changes and then push the code on remote username/ABC. After that developer raise the Merge request and Team lead will approve or reject the request.

Now Lets say developer worked on branch "B123" and then pushed it on remote. While raising the merge request, Gitlab will ask to which branch of Parent repo you want to merge it with. Now branch "B123" do not exists in project ABC and developer do not want to merge the changes to "parent/master" branch.

Also whenever some tag is deployed on test/staging servers, code is pulled from parent/ABC project. Code can't be pulled from usernamme/ABC project.

Is it possible the branch with same name i.e. B123 is created in project parent/ABC and then developer raise a merge request to merge the username/B123 branch to ABC/B123 branch?

Is there any other way to achieve same thing i.e. not merging in master branch but merge in new branch so that developer can test the code.

Comment: I think the testing should take place before the merge.  Also, can't you select the destination branch in your pull request?

Comment: We can't test before merging.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a merge request to let `B123` branch in fork repo also exist in the Parent/ABC. (sorry for I have no gitlab available now, and I will use github to show it):

1. Create a merge request in gitlab.
2. Change branches. Change the branch for Parent/ABC, even it has not `B123`, you can specify `B123` here (as I specify `oo` branch in github even though it’s not exist yet).

[image]

3. Submit merge request.

Comment: I am not getting any such option in gitlab. I mean you have to select the exiting target branch. Not sure if gitlab admin can enable or disable this thing.

Comment: It's also for github. Can't you input `B123` in blank and then press enter key even though this branch is not exist in dropdown list?

Comment: No. Not possible in gitlab.